Return output of subprocess.popen() in webserver
I have a Webserver in Python using Django.  I want to be able to kick of a long-running asynchronous subprocess and then have the client poll with a GET or POST and receive stdout as well as other information.  For each iteration, the server will return the lines of stdout that it has so far.  When the process ends, additional information will be returned.
How can I save the instance of cmd=subprocess.popen() so that on subsequent GET/POST, it can make the appropriate calls (e.g. cmd.poll, cmd.stdout.readline(), etc)
I've tried using Django's session manager, but the popen object is not Json serializable
Update
As suggested in the comments, instead of trying to save th popen object, I just continue the thread after the request has returned, and I save the stdout lines in the session.
But I'm having a problem updating the session object after the request has already returned.  It appears to be getting updated but upon the next request, the session object does not have any of the entries that were added after the request was completed.
Here is the code (views.py).  I'm using
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies' to specify cookie-based sessions.
import threading
from os.path import expanduser

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
import subprocess


# Separate thred to continue running our external task
def monitor_task(cmd, session):
    print('running thread')
    session['stdout'] = []
    while True:
        line = cmd.stdout.readline()
        print('line: ', line.replace('\n', ''))
        if not line:
            print('breaking')
            break
        session['stdout'].append(line.replace('\n', ''))

    print(session['stdout'])
    print('task is ending')


@api_view(['GET'])
def run_ngen(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cmd = subprocess.Popen([expanduser("~/testSpawn.sh"), "10"], shell=False, bufsize=-1,
                               encoding='utf-8',
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        x = threading.Thread(target=monitor_task, args=(cmd, request.session,))
        x.start()
        return Response('request started')


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_output(request):
    # GEt the output that was put into the session by monitor_task
    print('session: ', request.session.items())
    stdout = request.session['stdout']
    print('There are', len(stdout), 'lines')

    print(stdout)
    return Response(stdout)


The external program I'm running is
#!/bin/bash

sleep=5
if [ -n "$1" ]
  then
    sleep=$1
fi
echo line1
echo line2 
echo an error 1>&2

echo Sleeping for $sleep seconds
sleep $sleep
echo line3
echo another error 1>&2
echo line4

The problem I'm seeing is that any lines added to the session after the initial return of the request do not appear in the session later
The thread that runs the external task seems to work fine and adds all 5 lines to the session

However, when I hit the get_output endpoint that is supposed to return the contents of stdout, it only shows the first 3 lines (before the sleep)


What framework are you using for the Python webserver? Flask?

I'm using dJango.  Just updated the question to also note that I've tried using sessions

You could use a session variable to hold the output of the subprocess, then later GET/POST requests can return the latest output.

Oh, you mean just save the data on the backend as it comes out.... that might work.  But how can I immediately return the HTTP request, but continue to work in the background?

subprocess.Popen() returns immediately without waiting for the command to finish. So you can return immediately to the client.

Originally, I wanted to use the session or something like that because I didn't have anything else that needed to be in a database, so I thought I could get away without it.  But since you can't add to request.session outside the scope of a request, I realized that the only solution was to store the stdout lines in a database.
